# Can I use conditionals in Stack Navigator?

Tags: react-native, react-props, stack-navigator

I am new in this so I want to understand if I can use conditionals `if` and `else` inside navigate parameters.

So before Stack Navigator I was using the following code inside `app.js`

```
render() {
    var renderMainView = () => {
      if (this.props.user_id) {
        return (
          <Main />
        );
      } else {
        return (
          <Login />
        );
      }
    }
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1}}>
        <StatusBar barStyle="light-content"/>
        {renderMainView()}
        <AlertContainer/>
      </View>
    )
}
```

Now it looks like this

```
render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1}}>
        <StatusBar barStyle="light-content"/>
        <AppNavigator />
        <AlertContainer/>
      </View>
    )
  }
```

Inside Login.js it used to look like this

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={handleSubmit(_signIn)} style={{margin: 10, alignItems: 'center'}}>
  <Text style={{
   backgroundColor: 'steelblue', color: 'white', fontSize: 16,
   height: 37, width: 200, textAlign: 'center', padding: 10
}}>Login</Text>
```

My question now is how shall I pass inside `onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Main')}`, before going to Main screen, first call this `handleSubmit(_signIn)` and then check `this.props.use_id`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React-Navigation with Login Screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42876690/react-navigation-with-login-screen)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SwitchNavigator](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/switch-navigator.html) To achieve desired behavior

here's the example code:

```
const AppStack = StackNavigator({ Home: HomeScreen, Other: OtherScreen });
const AuthStack = StackNavigator({ SignIn: SignInScreen });

export default SwitchNavigator(
  {
    AuthLoading: AuthLoadingScreen,
    App: AppStack,
    Auth: AuthStack,
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'AuthLoading',
  }
);
```

> ***SwitchNavigator reference***
>
> SwitchNavigator(RouteConfigs, SwitchNavigatorConfig)
>
> [expo example](https://snack.expo.io/@react-navigation/auth-flow)