# Navigating out of Nested StackNavigator

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation, stack-navigator

How do you Navigate out of a Nested(ish) StackNavigator and DrawerNavigator, and disable the back key so that the user can't go back to the previous screen?

Below is the view hierarchy:

```js
const login = StackNavigator(
  {
    loginScreen: { screen: Login },
    firstPage: { screen: CodeCollab },
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: "firstPage"
  }
)

const main = StackNavigator(
  {
    home: { screen: Home },
  }
)

const homeDrawer = DrawerNavigator(
  {
    first: { screen: main },
  },
  {
    contentComponent: DrawerContent
  }
)

const out = StackNavigator(
  {
    Login: login,
    Home: homeDrawer,
    split: Splitter
  },
  {
    headerMode: 'none',
    title: 'Main',
    initialRouteName: "split"
  }
)

export default out
```

I'm trying to go from login/loginScreen to out/Home

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React-Navigation with Login Screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42876690/react-navigation-with-login-screen)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
this.props.navigation.dispatch(NavigationActions.back());
```