# Can a stack navigator have 2 different routes in react navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, stack-navigator

My project structure looks like this :

```
Tab navigator
|-Tab1
|-Tab2
    |-stack navigator
          |-login
              |
             screen1
              |
             screen2
               |
             screen3
|-Tab3
|-Tab4
```

I want my stack navigator route to start from screen1 once I enter the username and password for login screen. Is there any way we can achieve this?
Can we reroute/change the routes of stack navigator?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React-Navigation with Login Screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42876690/react-navigation-with-login-screen)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [SwitchNavigator](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/switch-navigator.html#switchnavigatorconfig) to change/reroute the screen stack

> I'm not using React Navigation V2, you should check the doc if you need more information about RNV2

Here's an example `TODO`:

in router.js (handling screen):

```
const Tab =  TabNavigator({
  Customer : {
    screen: Customer,
  }
});

const TabLogged =  TabNavigator({
  Handyman: {
    screen: Handyman,
  }
});
// here's the key to handle which account is logged
export const Check = SwitchNavigator({
  Auth: Auth,
  Account1: Tab,
  Account2: TabLogged
})
```

create Auth.js to check which account is logged or not:

```
class foo extends React.component{
  componentWillMount(){
    this.props.navigation.navigate(usertype == "isLoggedIn" ? 'Account2' : 'Account1');
  }

  render(){
    <View>
      <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#0000ff" />
      <StatusBar barStyle="default" />
    </View>
  }
}
```

and in your app.js or index.js :

```
class app extends Component{
  render() {
    return <check/>;
  }
}
```