# How to show login page instead of home page

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm using the default bottom tab navigation app from the expo example

My `appnavigator.js` looks like this

```
export default createAppContainer(createSwitchNavigator({
  // You could add another route here for authentication.
  // Read more at https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/auth-flow.html
  Main: MainTabNavigator,
}));
```

I want to check if the user is logged in, by checking the asyncstorage **loginname** value. In the `home.js`, if there is no **loginname**, then I want to redirect to the `sigin.js` page.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42876690/react-navigation-with-login-screen can you check this ?

Comment: Can you explain why you removed the whole code from your question? You just made it too broad.

Comment: because it's not necessary, the code was broad itself. And the question is quite simple. Also the answer is universal, it doesn't rely a specific code to understand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I worked it out. was very easy.

First do this in the appNavigator.js

```
import SignIn from '../screens/SignIn'

export default createAppContainer(createSwitchNavigator({
  // You could add another route here for authentication.
  // Read more at https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/auth-flow.html
  Main: MainTabNavigator,
  SignIn: SignIn // signIn is the login page
}));
```

Next, at the logic where you check for user logined do something like this.

```
AsyncStorage.getItem('loginname').then((value) => {
    console.log(value)
    this.props.navigation.navigate('SignIn')
})
```

the prop `this.props.navigation.navigate` is automatically avaiable in every stack, you dont need to pass it around to use it

Answer (score 3):

I suggest creating a file called initializing.js as a screen, which will be the first entry point in the app and put the logic there.

```
export default class Initializing extends Component {
  async componentDidMount() {
    try {
      const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('user_token');
      const skipOnBoarding = true;
      const authenticated = true;
      if (token) await goToHome(skipOnBoarding, authenticated);
      else await goToAuth();

      SplashScreen.hide();
    } catch (err) {
      await goToAuth();
      SplashScreen.hide();
    }
  }
 render() {
    return <View />;
  }
}
```